# Three.js; I've used Matrix for rotational transformation and it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, matrix, position, three.js, webgl

Thanks to ";" I was lost my last 2 days; Seemingly, after void main() {}, should not insert ; character..

anyway, I finally can draw curve through shader and try a new thing;

```
        attribute float sov;
        attribute float pl;
        attribute float oi;
        attribute vec3 color;
        varying vec3 vColor;

        void main() {
            // Convert pl, oi to degree;
            float u = radians(pl);
            float v = radians(oi);

            // Rotation Transform
                // Make xy-plane rotation matrix;
                mat3 plMat;
                    plMat[0][0] = cos(u);   plMat[0][1] = -sin(u);
                    plMat[1][0] = sin(u);   plMat[1][1] = cos(u);

                // Make line-base rotation matrix; by Rodriges
                mat3 oiMat;
                    oiMat[0][0] = cos(v)-(cos(v) - 1.0)*sin(u)*sin(u);
                    oiMat[0][1] = (1.0 - cos(v))*(-sin(u)*cos(u));
                    oiMat[0][2] = sin(v)*cos(u);
                    oiMat[1][0] = -sin(u)*cos(u)*(1.0 - cos(v));
                    oiMat[1][1] = cos(v)-(cos(v)-1.0)*cos(u)*cos(u);
                    oiMat[1][2] = sin(u)*sin(v);
                    oiMat[2][0] = -sin(v)*cos(u);
                    oiMat[2][1] = -sin(u)*sin(v);
                    oiMat[2][2] = cos(v);

            vec3 plPosition = plMat * position;
            vec3 oiPosition = oiMat * position;

            vColor = color;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(oiPosition, 1.0);
        }
```

I'v tried to rotate vertex position and I got this;

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Is this problem related to index of position?

If I read GLSL reference correctly, for array like 'position' must have it's index and maybe transform override this? ..

Please help me.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` is a JavaScript error. It has nothing to do with WebGL or GLSL. It means something is wrong in JavaScript.